# The database has been placed in a state by user 'Admin' on machine 'xyzusername' that prevents it being opened or locked

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, shared-directory

My application installed 250+ systems but the database(single) is shared in server machine. Which have every user read/write permission. some time I'm getting the above error from some systems.My purpose is collecting information from client systems and saving those information in server database.  My database is Access Database. Someone guide me pls.

Comment: Microsoft Jet can only handle a limited number of sessions. If your application uses a large number of ADO Data controls, Jet may run out of resources

Comment: Is there any other way to overcome from this issue and achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access db supports a max of 255 concurrent connections. notice that this value is the **maximum**! it's usually much less than that (affected by the system's resources).
If migrating to MSSQL [or other robust db platform] is not an option, I would recommend you to write a windows service (or other kind of process), which will run on the server, and manage all the database-related operations using some sort of locking mechanisms [e.g. Semaphores] to prevent exceeding the max supported concurrent connections

Comment: can split database concept help with this problem ?

Comment: That depends on your software architecture [does each app gets its own table? how important it is for the DBs to be synchronized, what are the connections between tables, etc etc]

Comment: At the time of login the client system insert some information on database.

Comment: I gave you solutions to your problem, I'm not going to advise you about the way you need to build your system.